# Error Installing magento 2.4.2 elasticsearch-7.11.1 xampp window

Tags: magento2.4.2

```
Installing search configuration...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php:665
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(665): Exception->__construct(NULL, 502)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(320): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\react\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Future\CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Core.php(341): in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 665

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php:665
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(665): Exception->__construct(NULL, 502)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(320): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\react\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Future\CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Core.php(341): in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24s\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 665
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/696185984738"}]}}
```

getting this error while installing magento 2.4.2 on window elasticsearch-7.11.1

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tutorial install elasticsearch on window: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycx__-2meLM
But if it not work for you, Can  you explain the steps when you install it?